# How can the cursor style be set for a div with contenteditable set to true in Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, contenteditable

Regardless of the style specified in CSS, it appears to be the "move" cursor with two sets of overlapping arrows.

Answer (score 0):

The below CSS should work - as long as there are no conflicting rules:

```
    [contenteditable=true]:hover{
        cursor:text;
    }
```

Tested in IE7, 8, 9, 10